# How to list available package versions using the dotnet cli?

Tags: nuget, dotnet-cli

Using the [dotnet cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) how can you list the available package versions for a specific package?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Short answer:*** It's not possible (as far as I know, as of Nov 25, 2019).

There are some other options, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

- You can see the [latest version(s) of *installed* packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package#options) you have that are outdated by running `dotnet list package --outdated` (requires .NET Core CLI 2.2+).
- You can manually view the available versions for a package at [nuget.org/packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/). Not a CLI
  option, but that's *an* option.

Comment: thanks. i came to the same conclusion.  will mark this as correct until/if the status changes

Comment: Not ideal but workaround would be to call i.e. `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json --version 100.1.1` with any version that we are sure does not exists and it will fail, but also in the output there will be latest version available. Not ideal but something I guess :)

Answer (score 5):

It's possible with "dotnet-search" a dotnet tool.

https://github.com/billpratt/dotnet-search

- You only need dotnet-core runtime 2.1
- Install via `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-search`
- Search via `dotnet search <package-name>`

Comment: That is very old runtime. Seems like this package is quite outdated.

Comment: Using this command throws an errorL `Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: JSON integer 4645432572 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'data[0].totalDownloads', line 1, position 1075.`

Answer (score 2):

A partial implementation of this feature now ships with **.NET 8.0.2**. While I don't see a way to list **all** available versions for a package, it can search for and show the most recent version, optionally including pre-release.

If you're looking to just check if a package exists, or check its latest version, you can use it like so:

```
dotnet package search <packageID>
```

The feature to list all versions may come at a later date, but this seems to be a good start.

Related github links:

- [dotnet cli github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6393)
- [NuGet github issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6060)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this CLI tool to work with a github enterprise package store... always throws `warn : Failed to retrieve metadata from source ...` error. Other mechanisms are working correctly.